# During adding new object to database inside AccountController An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.1

The `AccountController` has been created through template by Visual Studio. I want to record some actions made by user, one of them is logging in. The `ApplicationUserAction` holds info about action taken:

```
public class ApplicationUserAction {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Actor { get; set; }
}
```

Inside POST Login method I add new action to the db then want to save it:

```
  protected WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext db { get; set; }

    public AccountController() {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
...
...
...
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
        if (user != null) {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            //MY CODE
            Debug.WriteLine("HERE CODE");
            ApplicationUserAction action = new ApplicationUserAction { Description = "Logged in at " + DateTime.Now + " from IP " + Request.UserHostAddress + ".", TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Actor = user };
            db.ApplicationUserActions.Add(action);
            db.SaveChanges();
            //END OF MY CODE
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

but when I login I get to my web application I get this exception:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.


Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

This line caused exception:  `db.ApplicationUserActions.Add(action);`.

What went wrong, I didn't have any problems with adding something to the database yet.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks if it, when you create your action, you reference user, which is being tracked via another context (no code from UserManager, so it's hard to tell).

You'd have either detach the user from the previous context, or query a new instance of it from the current context.

---

**EDIT:** Content provided by the Original Poster:

This did the job.

```
ApplicationUser userSecondInstance = db.Users.Find(user.Id);
ApplicationUserAction action = new ApplicationUserAction { Description = "Logged in at " + DateTime.Now + " from IP " + Request.UserHostAddress + ".", TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Actor = userSecondInstance };
db.ApplicationUserActions.Add(action);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate in your answer why this is such problem?

Comment: When you load an entity from a context, the context keeps track of it. The framework won't allow an entity to be tracked by multiple contexts. So before that entity can be used by another context, you will need to detach it, either via the context.Detach method, or by loading a copy it it from the new context, as this example